# WooCommerce Price Variable Display on Single Product Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm actually working on a WooCommerce and I want to display a custom label at single product page that contain the product price divided by 12.

At the moment i'm doing it with a custom field manually input the price but I want to do it automatically

How can i get the product price variable and show it divided by 12

Something like
If the product has regular price divided by 12 if not get sale price and do it

Thanks for helping me.

---

**Edit:**

I can show the price divided by 12 with the following code on single product pages and products loop:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'change_displayed_sale_price_html', 10, 2 );
function change_displayed_sale_price_html( $price, $product ) {
     // Only on sale products on frontend and excluding min/max price on variable products
    if( $product->is_type('simple') ){
         // Get product prices
         $regular_price = (float) $product->get_regular_price(); // Regular price
         $sale_price = (float) $product->get_price(); // Active price (the "Sale price" when on-sale)
         
         $precision = 2; // Max number of decimals

         if (empty($sale_price)) {
            $cuotaprecioregular = round ($regular_price / 12, $precision);
            $price .= sprintf( __('<p class="saved-sale">12 cuotas de: %s</p>', 'woocommerce' ), $cuotaprecioregular );
         }
         else {
            $cuotapreciosale = round ($sale_price / 12, $precision);
            $price .= sprintf( __('<p class="saved-sale">12 cuotas de: %s</p>', 'woocommerce' ), $cuotapreciosale );
         }
    }
    return $price;
}
```

But also I'm trying to show the product price **with a 20% increment on a popup** page thats opens on my product page. With this function the price is showing it below the original price

How can I do the same but only show it in the desired popup?

Comment: First search in related answer using [`woocommerce_get_price_html` hook](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=a%3a%20woocommerce_get_price_html)

Comment: After this question addition / edit, you need to add in your question the related code that you are using for your custom popup… without thatnobody can really help you.